# Push segues can only be used by UINavigationController Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Getting a weird error when attempting to do a "push" sequence on a UIViewController.

I have embeded two UINavigationControllers into a root UIViewController.

I am basically attempting to make it so when the > button is pressed it pushes to the "View Controller."

Any ideas why I am getting the following error?:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

This is my storyboard:

http://cl.ly/image/3K0s3J1U1A3W

I am getting to the RecordViewController like so:

```
    RecordViewController *record = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RecordView"];
    [self presentViewController:record animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Why do you have two NavigationControllers? How are you triggering the segue?

Comment: You shouldn't have that second navigation controller. Just do a push  from RecordViewController to ViewController.

Comment: Your second navigation controller doesn't seem to make sense. Remove it and push straight from `RecordViewController` to `ViewController`. Keep also in mind that you can't push a navigation controller, you can only display it by presenting, not pushing

Comment: I tried doing that and getting the same error - @spassas

Comment: cc to my last message please @rdelmar

Comment: Is the first navigation controller your root view controller?

Comment: RecordViewController is a UIViewController with an embeded UINavigationController. RecordViewController is then made the root view, yes. @spassas

Comment: Your first NavigationController should be the root (initial) view controller, not the RecordVC

Comment: What do you mean? @spassas

Comment: Set the initial view controller to be your leftmost NavigationController, get rid of the second NavigationController (the one between `RecordViewController` and `ViewController`) and link the ">" button of your `RecordViewController` to `ViewController` with a push segue

Comment: What if I didn't want it to be the initial? For example, what if another ViewController was the initial and it modally presented the RecordViewController? Is that what is causing my issue? What should I do in that case? @spassas

Comment: Yes, that's probably what is causing your issue. So, please edit your post providing all the necessary details. Doing guesswork is really annoying

Comment: Check it out now if you can, please: @spassas - Also updated my photo.

Comment: You should present the navigation controller not RecordViewController. So, give the navigation controller an identifier, instantiate it, and present it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to push view controllers to a presented view controller, then your presented view controller must be a `UINavigationController`. In your case, give the leftmost navigation controller an identifier (i.e `RecordNavigationController`) and convert your code to:

```
UINavigationController *recordNavigationController = (UINavigationController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RecordNavigationController"];
[self presentViewController:recordNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```